# Why does my main not recognized my function in header and source 2 file?

Tags: c++

In my main I am calling the function ParseDeclars(pc, buffer). This function is declared in XMLParser.hpp and Is defined XMLParsser.cpp but when I call the function in my main my compiler gives me the error "no matching function for call to 'ParseDeclars'"

```
//srcreport.cpp
ParseDeclars(pc, buffer);
```

```
//XMLParser.hpp
#include "XMLParser.hpp"
void ParseDeclars(std::vector<char> pc, std::vector<char> buffer);
```

```
//XMLParser.cpp
#include "XMLParser.hpp"


void ParseDeclars(std::vector<char>::iterator pc, std::vector<char> buffer){
    std::vector<char>::iterator endpc = std::find(pc, buffer.end(), '>');
    if (endpc == buffer.end())
        exit(1);
    pc = std::next(endpc);
    pc = std::find_if_not(pc, buffer.end(), [] (char c) { return std::isspace(c); });
}
```

Error: no matching function for call to 'ParseDeclars'

Comment: There is a type mismatch, you declare a ParseDeclars with 2 vector arguments and you define it with an iterator and a vector.

Comment: @Zlatomir -- not to single you out, but comments about code are better written about the code, not about the person. "the code declares ... and defines it with ...". That reduces ego involvement.